# What Are Some Quirks/Surprises with Using .mm Files in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to use some C++ STL collections in my Objective-C iPhone app.  Apparently this is possible by giving files the extension ".mm" .  What are some of the quirks/surprises associated with this?

I want to use the basic containers that I'm familiar with (vector, queue, set, ...)

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Using C++ With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) for a detailed list of what you can and can't do.  You can do most things that you would expect.  You just can't do things like have a C++ class inherit from an Objective-C class or vice-versa, you can't mix C++ exceptions with Objective-C exceptions, and C++ introduces several new keywords not present in Objective-C.

Comment: Its too bac Apple f**k'd up the link. It now takes you to 'The Objective-C Programming Language'. Only 1 hit when searching for C++ (in case it was a sub-topic). Searching the site for the title ('Using C++ With Objective-C') returns 0 hits. Yeah Apple!

Comment: @noloader: Yep, it's unfortunate.  That article can still be found [on archive.org](http://replay.web.archive.org/20090423073703/http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).  It looks like Apple just completely deleted that chapter (as well as the chapter on Remote Messaging) from the "The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language" document.

Answer (score 5):

The major quirk of Objective-C++ is that if you don't pass -fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors to g++, it won't call the constructor and destructor of C++ instance variables in of ObjC objects. So remember to turn that option on and you should be good.

Comment: "On Mac OS X 10.4 and later, if you set the fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors compiler flag, you can use instances of C++ classes containing virtual functions and nontrivial user-defined zero-argument constructors and destructors as instance variables. (The fobjc-call-cxx-cdtors compiler flag is set by default in gcc-4.2.)" -- doc referred to by adam.

Comment: Now I understand why my constructors/destructors were being called without this option set in the project when using gcc-4.2 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The files will be compiled with the Objective-C++ compiler, so things will behave more like g++ than gcc, but since that's what you want it probably doesn't count as a surprise. From the Objective-C side, I'm not aware of any gotchas, and I've worked on several large projects that made significant used of Objective-C++. Just keep in mind that Objective-C reserved words are reserved in Objective-C++ as well, so you can occasionally run into issues with third-party C++ libraries (e.g., if they use "id" as a parameter in a public interface).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be surprised how well it works. I haven't really gotten into any problems intermixing Obj-C and C++ in a .mm file.